# Retrying Failed FCM messages using firebase-admin SDK for go

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm using the latest versions of the firebase-admin-sdk for Go so that I can send push notifications using FCM. I've build a client and I'm able to successfully send/receive notifications using the `SendMultiCast()` method.

The Firebase team recommends implementing a retry using he exponential back-off approach to handle failed requests. I've set up a back off that I've used in older FCM libraries. The issues is I'm not sure on which type of error I should act on in my retry logic in order to replay the request. I believe it's normally best to only do that in the case of network delivery issues.

Here's the basic retry...I've commented out the code in it looking for net.Errors since it doesn't seem like the admin SDK returns something like that. I know that the `SendMultiCast()` method returns an error and a `BatchResponse`. Is the error response what I should retry on or is it something in the `BatchResponse`? I can't seem to find what I would retry on in the batch response.

```
const (
    minBackoff = 100 * time.Millisecond
    maxBackoff = 1 * time.Minute
)

func retry(fn func() error, attempts int) error {
    var attempt int
    for {
        err := fn()
        log.Println("attempt to send")
        if err == nil {
            return nil
        }
        
        // This is what has worked in past libs since I could expect 
        // net.errors signifying a timeout or some sort of http issue that would
        // require a retry
        // if tErr, ok := err.(net.Error); !ok || !tErr.Temporary() {
        //   return err
        // }

        attempt++
        backoff := minBackoff * time.Duration(attempt*attempt)

        if attempt > attempts || backoff > maxBackoff {
            return err
        }

        time.Sleep(backoff)
    }
}
```

Below is a snippet of how I'm attempting to use the Retry...

```
func (c *Client) Send(ctx context.Context, msg *messaging.MulticastMessage) (*FCMv1Response, error) {
    res := new(FCMv1Response)
    err := retry(func() error {
        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, DefaultTimeout)
        defer cancel()
        var er error
        res.FailedTokens, er = c.sendMulticastMessage(ctx, msg)
        return er
    }, RetryAttempts)

    if err != nil {
        c.logger.Error("errorSendingLLUNotification", zap.Error(err))
        return nil, err
    }
    return res, nil

}

func (c *Client) sendMulticastMessage(ctx context.Context, msg *messaging.MulticastMessage) ([]string, error) {
    br, err := c.msg.SendMulticast(ctx, msg)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var failedTokens []string
    if br.FailureCount > 0 {
        for idx, resp := range br.Responses {
            if !resp.Success {
                // The order of responses corresponds to the order of the registration tokens.
                failedTokens = append(failedTokens, msg.Tokens[idx])
            }
        }
    }
    return failedTokens, nil
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
br, err := client.SendMulticast(ctx, msg)
if err != nil {
  // total failure
}

if br.FailureCount > 0 {
  // partial failure
}
```

You don't have to retry on total failures. The SDK handles that automatically. By the time your code sees the above error it has already been retried several times with no success, or the error was not eligible for retry at all.

For partial failures the [`messaging.SendResponse`](https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go/v4/messaging#SendResponse) type includes an error that can be passed through the error handling functions of the `messaging` package or the new `errorutils` package to determine if it's eligible for retry. Typically you would only want to retry on cases where [`messaging.IsUnavailable()`](https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go/v4/messaging#IsUnavailable) returns true.

You need to also make sure that the retries only send to tokens that failed in the previous attempts. I don't see that logic in the code you have given above.

Comment: @HiranyaJaythilaka Thanks! After reviewing things a bit more it looks like the multicast approach isn't actually going to work with my specific requirement now. Does the `Send()` method also have a built in retry?

Comment: Yes, `Send()` has built-in retries for all eligible errors.